# Custom folder icon on USB

Tags: usb, icons, removable-media, desktop.ini

I am trying to make custom folder icons for my USB. I have changed the `\desktop.ini` to reflect where my icon is located. I have placed the icons in the corresponding folders within my USB and hid them. Here is what my desktop.ini looks like:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=F:\PRODUCT CATALOG 2017\Product Catalog.ico,0
```

The problem I am finding is when I move the USB to another computer that uses a different drive letter (mine is `F:\`) then it is not recognized. How can I code this so it will work on all computers?

Comment: I suggest, that you shouldn't create a `desktop.ini`, but a `autorun.inf` for a drive (the root directory of a mount point).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the Drive Letter defining an absolute path, you can use the path without the drive letter like:

```
[.ShellClassInfo] IconResource=\PRODUCT CATALOG 2017\Product Catalog.ico,0
```

This way Windows will look from the root (\) of the current drive, into the `PRODUCT CATALOG 2017` folder.

If otherwise the icon file is in the same folder than the `desktop.ini` file, not even the path is necessary, just including the ico filename is enough.

```
[.ShellClassInfo] IconResource=Product Catalog.ico,0
```

Comment: The backslash isn't even necessary as long as the ini and the ico are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

In case the desktop.ini and the *.ico files are located in the same folder, you could also just do:
`IconResource=yourFile.ico,0`

As far I understand, the FileResource Tag is rather about using a dll or similar, which contains multiple icons. You should also be able to use:
`IconFile=yourFile.ico`

Please note that I would have commented to the first answer, but I do not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: An ico can't contain multiple icons. It can only contain different resolutions of the same icon. But a dll can have multiple icons in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the other two answers and use the desktop.ini file, or you can also make a file called `autorun.inf` and enter the following code:

```
[autorun]
Label=What you want your drive to be named
Icon=icon.ico (or the name of your file, I believe mostly any image will work)
```

Save the file and then hide it and your icon if you wish to keep the folders on your USB nice and clean, I also believe you can completely remove the "Label".

---

Edit: If you would like to use a icon from a dll or exe it would be something along the lines of `Icon=yourfile.exe,1` To represent the SECCOND icon (0 is the first) within the exe. Just replace "exe" with "dll" to use a dll file, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017030/what-does-icon-setup-exe-1-mean-in-autorun-inf%20here)

Comment: An ico can't contain multiple icons. It can only contain different resolutions of the _same_ icon. But a dll can have multiple icons in it.

Comment: @iBug You can actually still point to a icon from a dll.

Comment: Personally I don't prefer this as nowadays autorun.inf is very likely to be regcognized as a virus on non-CD drives.

Comment: @iBug That's very possible, but even if it was to have the "run" command in it the file wouldn't be executed on a newer version of windows nor would it be blocked off, it would just be listed as an option. I personally use an autorun file to fix the name on my USB drive as well as to use a custom icon. I don't run into any issue with it.

Comment: Obviously Windows Defender (Win8+) and Microsoft Security Essentials (Win7-, not built-in) do not block `autorun.inf`, but a variety of 3rd-party antivirus & security softwares recognize it as a virus since nowadays few legit softwares come with one.

Answer (score 0):

Create text file with put this one in:

```
[autorun]
Icon=Liou D. Doragon.ico
```

After create file change txt to `autorun.inf` and save to your hard drive or USB flash drive.

But dont forget to create `Liou D. Doragon.ico`

Put picture in `x2ico` to make your icon. Choose name you want `abc.ico` is okay.

And put it same place you place this inf. When you plug in your USB flash drive or hard drive. Autorun will automatic change your hard drive folder

It work for all my USB flash drives and hard drives.

BTW, if laptop or computer blocks autorun then this one won't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]